# Robocopy hide destination folder after copy

Tags: robocopy

i want to copy a file from D:\ to another folder.
So the issue is that robocopy hides the destinationfolder after the copy action.
I already tried diffent options but nothing worked.

This is my robocopy command:

```
ROBOCOPY "D:\\" "D:\\abc" "Setup*.*xml" /NP /S /A-:SH /FFT /R:0 /W:0
```

The confusing point is that the hidden destinationfolder is not displayed in the fileexplorer, but when i insert directly the destinationfolder in the path field the content will be displayed in the fileexplorer

Answer (score -1):

I solved my Problem.
I changed the attributes of the destinationfolder after the ROBOCOPY command and everything is fine.

I used this command:

```
attrib -s -h "D:\\abc"
```